# HTML5 Drag and Drop anywhere on the screen

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have a debugger log that I've written in JavaScript for a project I'm working on. The log is basically an `<aside>` tag in HTML5 that only shows when needed. I wanted to play around with the idea of being able to move the log around the screen, as it may overlap certain things (which is fine for my project). However, I can't seem to figure out how to use HTML5 to properly drag and drop the  tag so that it can be placed anywhere on the screen (well, or within a `<div>` element).

After reading on HTML5's drag and drop support, I have a basic understanding of how it works, but I'm not sure where to start when it comes to allowing the div to be placed anywhere (it's z-index is a high value, so as I said, overlapping is fine).

Any suggestions?

Oh, and I'd like to try and avoid using external libraries for this project, wherever possible. I'm trying to do this in pure JavaScript/HTML5.

Comment: Have you tried any tutorial? For instance [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/dnd/basics/).

Comment: Yeah, in fact, I already had that tab open. I should say I skimmed it, as oppose to following it exactly, but to me, it looks like they're basically re-organizing the contents of their columns. What I'm trying to do is get one element to move anywhere on the screen, and stay at that new position.

Comment: Maybe a layer of overlapping divs/"columns" (to make the drop more accurate) inheriting the debugger log tag's size and covering the whole page.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a little CSS to change the location.  Might not have that dnd yumminess, but it would certainly be able to relocate your data.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Drag and drop doesn't move elements around, if you want the element to move when you drop it then you have to set the new position of the element in the drop event.  I've [done an example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/kKuqH/) which works in Firefox and Chrome, here are the key points:

```
function drag_start(event) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(event.target, null);
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain",
    (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left"),10) - event.clientX) + ',' + (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("top"),10) - event.clientY));
}
```

The `dragstart` event works out the offset of the mouse pointer from the left and top of the element and passes it in the `dataTransfer`.  I'm not worrying about passing the ID because there's only one draggable element on the page - no links or images - if you have any of that stuff on your page then you'll have to do a little more work here.

```
function drop(event) {
    var offset = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain").split(',');
    var dm = document.getElementById('dragme');
    dm.style.left = (event.clientX + parseInt(offset[0],10)) + 'px';
    dm.style.top = (event.clientY + parseInt(offset[1],10)) + 'px';
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

The `drop` event unpacks the offsets and uses them to position the element relative to the mouse pointer.

The `dragover` event just needs to `preventDefault` when anything is dragged over.  Again, if there is anything else draggable on the page you might need to do something more complex here:

```
function drag_over(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

So bind it to the `document.body` along with the `drop` event to capture everything:

```
var dm = document.getElementById('dragme');
dm.addEventListener('dragstart',drag_start,false);
document.body.addEventListener('dragover',drag_over,false);
document.body.addEventListener('drop',drop,false);
```

If you want this to work in IE you'll need to convert the `aside` to an `a` element, and, of course, all the event binding code will be different.  The drag and drop API doesn't work in Opera, or on any mobile browsers as far as I'm aware.  Also, I know you said you don't want to use jQuery, but cross browser event binding and manipulating element positions are the sort of things that jQuery makes much easier.

Comment: Is this code made to work with more than one drag gable box at a time ?

Comment: What if you have more than one dragable box?

Comment: if you want it to work in IE 10 and 11 change the first argument in setData and getData from "text/plain" to "text".  http://jsfiddle.net/131udfnm/1/

Comment: Could this be made to support a large library of lets say 50+ items?

Answer (score 12):

Thanks for your answer. It works great in Chrome and Firefox. I tweaked it to work in IE.Below is the code.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">
        <meta name="dcterms.created" content="Fri, 27 Jun 2014 21:02:23 GMT">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
        <title></title>
        
        <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
     <style>
     li
     { 
          position:  absolute;
          left: 0;
          top: 0; /* set these so Chrome doesn't return 'auto' from getComputedStyle */
          width: 200px; 
          background: rgba(255,255,255,0.66); 
          border: 2px  solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
          border-radius: 4px; padding: 8px;
     }
     </style>
     <script>
            function drag_start(event) {
                var style = window.getComputedStyle(event.target, null);
                var str = (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left")) - event.clientX) + ',' + (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("top")) - event.clientY) + ',' + event.target.id;
                event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", str);
            }

            function drop(event) {
                var offset = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text").split(',');
                var dm = document.getElementById(offset[2]);
                dm.style.left = (event.clientX + parseInt(offset[0], 10)) + 'px';
                dm.style.top = (event.clientY + parseInt(offset[1], 10)) + 'px';
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }

            function drag_over(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
     </script>
      </head>
      <body ondragover="drag_over(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">
       <ul>
              <li id="txt1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)"> Drag this text </li><br>
              <li id="txt2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)"> Drag me</li>
      </ul>
          <p>I never am really satisfied that I understand anything; because, understand it well as I may, my comprehension can only be an infinitesimal fraction of all I want to understand about the many connections and relations which occur to me, how the matter in question was first thought of or arrived at, etc., etc.</p>
          <p>In almost every computation a great variety of arrangements for the succession of the processes is possible, and various considerations must influence the selections amongst them for the purposes of a calculating engine. One essential object is to choose that arrangement which shall tend to reduce to a minimum the time necessary for completing the calculation.</p>
          <p>Many persons who are not conversant with mathematical studies imagine that because the business of [Babbage’s Analytical Engine] is to give its results in numerical notation, the nature of its processes must consequently be arithmetical and numerical, rather than algebraical and analytical. This is an error. The engine can arrange and combine its numerical quantities exactly as if they were letters or any other general symbols; and in fact it might bring out its results in algebraical notation, were provisions made accordingly.</p>
          <p>The Analytical Engine has no pretensions whatever to originate anything. It can do whatever we know how to order it to perform. It can follow analysis, but it has no power of anticipating any analytical revelations or truths. Its province is to assist us in making available what we are already acquainted with.</p>
    
      </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 8):

I adjusted a bit *robertc*'s great answer for cases of multiple items. Here the `second`class name is just for another position.

```
<aside draggable="true" class="dragme" data-item="0">One</aside>
<aside draggable="true" class="dragme second" data-item="1">Two</aside>
```

Add the data-item attribute to the `setData`function.

```
function drag_start(event) {
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(event.target, null);
  event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left"), 10) - event.clientX) + ',' + (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("top"), 10) - event.clientY) + ',' + event.target.getAttribute('data-item'));
}
```

Target the element that is dragged.

```
function drop(event) {
  var offset = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain").split(',');
  var dm = document.getElementsByClassName('dragme');
  dm[parseInt(offset[2])].style.left = (event.clientX + parseInt(offset[0], 10)) + 'px';
  dm[parseInt(offset[2])].style.top = (event.clientY + parseInt(offset[1], 10)) + 'px';
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
```

And loop through all elements with a class `dragme`.

```
var dm = document.getElementsByClassName('dragme');
for (var i = 0; i < dm.length; i++) {
  dm[i].addEventListener('dragstart', drag_start, false);
  document.body.addEventListener('dragover', drag_over, false);
  document.body.addEventListener('drop', drop, false);
}
```

[pen](http://codepen.io/ingvi/pen/NNjWyN?editors=0010)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, `body` does not have the exact dimensions of the page. In that case, the element cannot be dragged outside the boundary of `body`.

Here is the solution that works best for me:

```js
const myElement = document.getElementById("my-element");

myElement.addEventListener("dragstart", (evt) => {
  evt.dataTransfer.setData("id", "my-element");

  const boundingRect = myElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  const offset = {
    x: evt.clientX - boundingRect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - boundingRect.top,
  };
  evt.dataTransfer.setData("offset", JSON.stringify(offset));
});

document.documentElement.addEventListener("dragover", (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
});

document.documentElement.addEventListener("drop", (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();

  if (evt.dataTransfer.getData("id") === "my-element") {
    const offset = JSON.parse(evt.dataTransfer.getData("offset"));
    const xPos = evt.clientX - offset.x;
    const yPos = evt.clientY - offset.y;
    myElement.style.left = `${xPos}px`;
    myElement.style.top = `${yPos}px`;
    myElement.style.bottom = "auto";
    myElement.style.right = "auto";
  }
});
```

```css
#my-element {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-element" draggable="true">Drag me anywhere</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All of these answers use the native drag and drop which is not quite the same thing as drag and element and not really "dropping" it. There is a great demo [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp) if you want to move an element around the screen randomly. Better visibility while dragging.