# Drag drop with handle

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I have a div which contains a span that is 16x16px. I want the drag event to start when user clicks and drags this icon but it should drag the whole div. I'm trying to follow this tutorial here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

I cant figureout how to do this with a handle. Please adivise.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I have slightly modified SaphuA's answer to allow highlighting text.

The trick is not to add the `draggable` attribute until the drag handle gets the `mousedown` event.

Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/a6tgy9so/1/

Comment: Oo that was an important note to share. Accepted this answer instead. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: great idea! Kudos to @SaphuA for the original idea too

Comment: There is a bug when you click on the handle (not move it, just click), then `draggable` attribute remains `true`.

Comment: @Traxo I've updated the demo, there's now a mouseup handler to prevent this

Comment: Works great except could you please add how to actually drop the window to where you dragged it to? I have an ondrop event on a surrounding BODY element, but can't get the window to move to exactly where I dropped it.

Comment: @user1343035 In that case you need to change the CSS position of the dragged element. See [this example from MDN that I modified](https://jsfiddle.net/zsLkme7g/2/) (the [original is here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/drop_event))

Comment: I know its a long time ago, but for anyone looking for some simple doing in React with no deps.
Adding `onMouseDown={e=>setDrag(true)} onTouchStart={e=>setDrag(true)} onMouseUp={e=>setDrag(false)} onTouchEnd={e=>setDrag(false)}` to the **handle** element and `draggable={canDrag}` to the **draggable** one works like a charm.

Answer (score 33):

Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/pwt1cbjc/

```js
var draggable = document.getElementById('draggable');
var handle = document.getElementById('handle');
var target = false;
draggable.onmousedown = function(e) {
    target = e.target;
};
draggable.ondragstart = function(e) {
    if (handle.contains(target)) {
        e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'handle');
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
};
```

```css
#draggable {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#handle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid black;
    cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<h1>Drag Handle</h1>

<div id="draggable" draggable="true">
    <div id="handle">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow thank you this is cool, the div is not moved though on drop, is it possible to add that? Also is it possible to add slide animation as user moves around?

Comment: Didn't expect you still needed an answer for this old question, haha! Came across it by accident and decided to answer it anyway. About dropping, take a look at the answer here for some sample code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230834/html5-drag-and-drop-anywhere-on-the-screen

Comment: I went about it another way, it was much more intensive (on mousedown i added mousemove listener, and on mousemove i would set the elment `left`,`top` and it followed the cursor in nice animated way), your way is very nice and i feel more performant, and I would love to adapt it.

Comment: This is a good solution if you don't care about copy/paste of any content within the dragged tile. If you do care about that then this version isn't for you.

Comment: Pay Attention for this to work the selected item must be direct child of draggable element not `n+2` child