# Make only part of a div draggable

Tags: javascript, html, draggable, handle

How do i create something similar to  to jquery's "draggable handles" in Javascript?

(Jquery is unfortunately not an option for me.)

I have div called "dxy" within it I have another div called "draggable_handle". At the moment I can drag *dxy* around wherever I press. How do I make is so that I can drag *dxy* around, but only when i press on *draggable_handle* and no where else in the div?

```
<div id="dxy">
  <div id="draggable_handle">
    <p>
    Draggable part
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I made a JsFiddle, which will make what I mean clearer, here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lk2hLthp/7/

Please add some code examples or a jsfiddle as I am a newbie. =)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drag drop with handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26283661/drag-drop-with-handle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add event listeners to inner element instead of outer like this:

```
function addListeners() {
  document.getElementById('draggable_handle').addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
}
```

Comment: Ah it was so simple. I would probably not have figured it out without asking anyway. Thanks for the quick reply! =)

Comment: You are welcome! Don't forget to mark question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know If I understood what you're trying to do but adding the "mousedown" listener to draggable_handle works for me:

```
document.getElementById('draggable_handle').addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, merely changing what id you grab in the addListeners function will give you what you need:
`document.getElementById('draggable_handle').addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);`

instead of:
`document.getElementById('dxy').addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);`

I forked you fiddle and made the change: http://jsfiddle.net/BlessYAHU/f687ppg8/

This works because in your functions (mouseDown, divMove), you get the container dom element (dxy).