# What do I have to change so that dragging is only possible over a certain area / handle?

Tags: javascript, list, drag-and-drop, draggable, droppable

I have a list of two droppable boxes where the items can be moved from one box to the other. Now I would like to make it moveable via a handle area.
What do I need to change so that dragging is only possible over a certain area - handle (e.g. the rest selectable text)?

```
  document.addEventListener('dragstart', e => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('draggable')) {
    dragging = e.target;
    dragging.classList.add('dragging');
    cloned = dragging.cloneNode(true);
  }
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Reksio/kp21vzms/10/)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hello Shenya, I have a question, what do you mean by "the rest selectable text"?
Would you like to drag the whole item by using the handle and the handle only?

Comment: @Thomas the rest can be a selectable text for example. The content.

Comment: and the grip surface / handle area is the grip / handle for the element that can only be moved with that grip / handle like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26283661/drag-drop-with-handle

Comment: It should look something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Reksio/kp21vzms/16/. Except that I would also like to use links in the content container. How can I make this better?